# Testing for divergence of a sequence

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of nonnegative random variables, and consider the following null and alternative hypotheses:

$$H_0: X_n=c+o_p(1) \quad \text{as}\quad n\to\infty$$

$$H_1: X_n=O_p(1/n) \quad \text{as}\quad n\to\infty$$

where $c>0$ is an unknown constant. How can I construct a test statistic $\xi_n=f(X_n)$ to test this null hypothesis? The statistic $\xi_n$ should converge to a null distribution under $H_0$ and be consistent under $H_1$.

If we consider the sequence $Y_n=n X_n$, then the previous two hypotheses become

$$H_0: Y_n\overset{p}\to\infty \quad \text{as}\quad n\to\infty$$

$$H_1: Y_n=O_p(1) \quad \text{as}\quad n\to\infty$$

Any ideas how to proceed here? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Perhaps instead of looking at $Y_n=nX_n$ you could look at the sum $Z_n=\sum{X_n}$? First thing that came to my mind, sorry if it isn't helpful.

Comment: My reasoning being $Z_n/n$ might have good statistical properties for large $n$.

Comment: @Samuel In my setting we only observe a single $X_n$. We don't observe the whole sequence.

Comment: It seems clear to me that either we need more samples of $X_n$, or we need more information about $o_p(1)$ and $O_p(1/n)$. For example, $o_p(1)$ might be $Z_n/\log(1+n)$ while $O_p(1/n)$ is $Z_n/n$, where $Z_n \sim N(0, 1)$ or something.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $1/\sqrt{n}$ goes to 0 slower than $1/n$. Now consider $\xi_n= 1\{X_n>1/\sqrt{n}\}$.

Under $H_0$, let $Z_n:=X_n-c=o_p(1)$. Then if  $1/\sqrt{n}<c/2$:

$$P(\xi_n=0)=P(X_n\leq 1/\sqrt{n})=P(Z_n\leq 1/\sqrt{n}-c)\leq P(Z_n \leq -c/2)\to 0.$$
So $\xi_n \to 1$ (in distribution).

Under $H_1$, let $Y_n:=nX_n= O_p(1)$. Then
$$P(\xi_n=0)=P(X_n\leq 1/\sqrt{n})=P(Y_n\leq\sqrt{n})\to1.$$
So $\xi_n \to 0$ (in distribution).

I wouldn't use this in practice, but in theory it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I was looking for a nondegenerate distribution under the null in order to  build confidence intervals. Do you see a way to do this?

Comment: May I also ask why you wouldn't use this in practice?